# Storing data in the db as crypted, and retrieving

Tags: php, mysql

For example:

```
$text = "sample";
$salt = "sh54mdR";
```

I'd like to store $text value in the db as encrypted by using $salt value. result should be like that:

```
jkhdnewewjhjjhnd (it's just an example, so I want to hide $text value)
```

than id like to de-crypt "jkhdnewewjhjjhnd" to "sample" I can't use md5, sha etc. I'm looking for a way to store the value and than de-crypt it. do you know a PHP function for my request?

Comment: Have you looked at the mcrypt functions? http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php  Or on the DB side there is encode/decode http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html

Comment: Check the [Mcrypt Functions](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php).

Comment: Your `$salt` is actually a key, maybe rename your variable `$key`. ( 'salt' is used for hashing, and random by definition)

Comment: thanks.. im checking them right now. thanks.. +1

Comment: If you just want to make the text non-human-readable but are not that bothered about security (although I suspect you are) here is something quick and dirty that I sometimes use, to encode `$enc = rot13(base64_encode(strrev($str)));` and to decode `$str = strrev(base64_decode(rot13($enc)));`

Comment: It's worth noting here that one problem with symmetric crypto alone is the encrypt/decrypt key must be sitting there in the PHP file. Steal the hard drive and you get everything. Probably OK for everything but medical, financial and nuclear launch codes though :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the **[mcrypt functions](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php)**.

Encrypt:

```
$key = "this is a secret key";
$input = "Let us meet at 9 o'clock at the secret place.";

$encrypted_data = mcrypt_ecb (MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $input, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
```

Decrypt:

```
$decrypted = mbcrypt_ecb(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $encrypted_data, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
```

See examples from http://us.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php

Don't forget to use base64_encode() before storing in the database, unless the column accepts binary data.

Answer (score 0):

use the Mcrypt library, it supports lots of ciphers (see the list here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php)

An example:

```
$text = "sample";
$salt = "sh54mdR";

$encrypted_data = mcrypt_ecb (MCRYPT_3DES, $salt, $text, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
```